# Understanding the Inheritance hierarchy in OOP

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When Looking at the inheritance hierarchy trees in OOP when two objects are side by side in the diagram what is their relationship to each other? For example: NSWindow and NSView both inherit from NSResponder, so are they siblings? How do their respective methods relate?

Comment: How 'bout you crop the screenshot next time, so we can pretend to ourselves you actually bought that book? ;) The author of it in particular, who's most likely on stackoverflow, just as you and me? [/OT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only relation you can tell from the diagram, is that they have the same parent. The only thing that you can surely tell is that they share what they inherit from their common parent.

As they are so closely related, there are probably other similarities, for example their purpose. However, that is not evident from the inheritance tree.